# How to persist a List of Entities from multiple Subclasses

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm using hibernate and want to create a property that contains a list of Entities from different classes. Each class inherits the same Interface/Abstract.

Can this be done with hibernate or jpa and what do i have to configure?

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the inheritance mapping for your child entities. This should be a good start: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6906 .